# UIBarButtonItem doesn't change default blue color after enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

In my code I have:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnStart;
```

And then:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.btnStart.enabled = NO;
}
```

The button change color to gray and if I touch it, nothing happens, it's right. I've another piece of code:

```
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state {
    if (state == MCSessionStateConnected) {
        NSLog(@"I'm connected to peer '%@'", peerID.displayName);
        self.btnStart.enabled = YES;
    }
 }
```

The problem is that the button doesn't change color, until I touch it. The NSLog works perfectly.

Comment: have you tried to use `[self.btnStart setEnabled:YES]`? It seems like the button becomes active, but just don't change its style. Maybe this is done in the `isEnabled`-setter

Comment: always the same. I tried also self.btnStart.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; but it doesn't change color until I touch it...

Comment: have you tried to execute this line  self.btnStart.enabled = YES; on the main thread ? like this :  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.btnStart.enabled = YES;
});

Comment: Wooow! It works, thank you very much. Can you say me why this happens?

Comment: Sorry to jump in, but that's right. You cannot change the view from another thread that's not running in the main thread queue. maybe [this](https://chritto.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/updating-the-ui-from-another-thread/) explains a little better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update UI elements on the main thread.

Do something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
  //add the needed code below
  self.btnStart.enabled = YES; 
});
```